# Running redis with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose, nestjs

```
version: '3'
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "5674:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis_cache:
    image: bitnami/redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  app:
    image: asobooks-api
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      NODE_ENV: prod
      DB_CONNECTION: postgres
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_PORT: 5432
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis_cache
    command:
      [
        'node',
        'dist/src/main.js'
      ]
```

I have been trying this for about 2 days now and unfortunately, the app container fails to connect to Redis.
`Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

Here is the connection.

```
BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: Queues.EMAIL,
      redis: {
        port: 6379,
        host: 'redis_cache',
      },
    })
```

Please help me with this thing it works without using docker. But fails when I run in containers. Thanks.

Comment: If the error message says `127.0.0.1` then the `host:` setting you show isn't taking effect.  How is that getting loaded or used in your application?

Comment: Try giving your redis service a `container_name` of `redis_cache` and see if that helps.   Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name

Comment: Thanks, @Zacx. It is not still working

Comment: @uncle-tee have you found a solution? having the same issue here